# Mobile app Collects Children's Data

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, australia, health

We are working on a medical app for children.  (Of course parents will access the application.)

Is it lawful to store children's health records on a webserver?

My client says it's illegal; that we should always store the data on a remote local server to protect the minor's protected information.

Is this the case?

Comment: Are you asking for all of these countries, or for _any_ of these countries? That is, do you want the answer to consider them all, or would just one be sufficient?

Comment: "remote local server" -- what could that possibly mean?

Comment: @feetwet Local server means your own iphone or android device, Remote server means somewhere on the hosting companies datasource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the United States, the main statute governing the use of health care information is HIPAA, the Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act.

HIPAA and its related statutes and regulations detail what you can and can't do with medical information. You can't always collect it; if you do, you can't always share it, and you can't always delete it.

This is a complex field of law and it's easy to screw up in a way that would cause big, serious, company-destroying, job-ending problems for everyone involved.

To put this another way: this is absolutely, positively, not something you want to get advice on from strangers on the internet. You don't just need a lawyer; you need a HIPAA specialist--or the equivalent in whatever other countries you plan to operate in--before you push anything out to real-life patients, especially children.